# PHP Get Current year after current month

Tags: php, date

I am using this code to get current year

```
echo date("Y");
```

I also have a variable for the name of the month

```
$month= "November"
```

Now it's November and I am getting 2016 which is correct with my code.

However in December, I want to get November 2017 because November 2016 has expired.

How could I go about this?

My code:

```
<?php the_field('fl_month');echo date("Y"); ?>
```

Comment: Where is you code?

Comment: just posted, don't know what else to do here

Comment: the_field suggests this is inside a Wordpress app? Correct?

Comment: yes this is wordpress

Comment: Because the PHP should be: echo strftime( '%B %Y' ); But somehow I don't think that will get translated to Wordpress But just end up somewhere on the page.

Comment: Or: echo date( 'F Y' );

Comment: Look into PHPs strtotime  function. Adding months, weeks etc is pretty easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// incoming month
$month = 'November';
$monthNumber = date("n", strtotime($month));

// current month
$currentMonth = date("n");

if ($currentMonth >= $monthNumber) {
    echo $month . ' ' . date('Y', strtotime('+1 year'));
} else {
    echo $month . ' ' . date('Y');
}
```

So I am converting the incoming and current month to number format, checking if current month is bigger or equal than incoming and then based on that, I decide if it should be next year.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each month until you find the next occurrence of November:

```
$month = 'August';
echo myyear($month); // 2017
$month = 'November';
echo myyear($month); // 2016

function myyear($month) {
  $dt = strtotime($month);
  $target = date('m', $dt);
  if (date('m', time()) == date('m', $dt)) return date('Y');
  do {
    $dt = strtotime('next month', $dt);
  } while ($target != date('m', $dt));
  return date('Y', $dt);
}
```